# Return a set of objects from a class

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I have a method that adds a new item to an EF table, then queries back the table to return a subset of the table. It needs to return to the caller a set of "rows", each of which is a set of columns. I'm not sure how to do this. I have some code, but I think it's wrong. I don't want to return ONE row, I want to return zero or more rows. I'm not sure what DataType to use... [qryCurrentTSApproval is an EF object, referring to a small view in SS. tblTimesheetEventlog is also an EF object, referring to the underlying table]

Ideas?

```
    private qryCurrentTSApproval LogApprovalEvents(int TSID, int EventType)
    {
        using (CPASEntities ctx = new CPASEntities())
        {
            tblTimesheetEventLog el = new tblTimesheetEventLog();
            el.TSID = TSID;
            el.TSEventType = EventType;
            el.TSEUserName = (string)Session["strShortUserName"];
            el.TSEventDateTime = DateTime.Now;
            ctx.tblTimesheetEventLogs.AddObject(el);
            ctx.AcceptAllChanges();

            var e = (from x in ctx.qryCurrentTSApprovals
                     where x.TSID == TSID
                     select x);
            return (qryCurrentTSApproval)e;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your method return type to a collection of `qryCurrentTSApproval`

```
private List<qryCurrentTSApproval> LogApprovalEvents(int TSID, int EventType)
{
   using (CPASEntities ctx = new CPASEntities())
   {
     //  some other existing code here 

     var itemList = (from x in ctx.qryCurrentTSApprovals
                                     where x.TSID == TSID
                                                  select x).ToList();
     return itemList;
   }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was trying to get to. Thank you.